# C言語で「CMakeLists.txt」 があるフォルダーからslnファイルの作成について

Tags: c, visual-studio, cmake

CMakeLists.txt があるフォルダーからslnファイルを作成しました。
中身の概要は次のとおりです。

**CMakeLists.txt**

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.0.0)
project(777 VERSION 1.0.0)

include_directories(includes)

add_executable(777 
    Source/111.c
    Source/222.c
    Source/333.c

    ･･････（省略）･･････

    Source/777.c
    Source/888.c
    Source/999.c
)

set(CPACK_PROJECT_NAME ${PROJECT_NAME})
set(CPACK_PROJECT_VERSION ${PROJECT_VERSION})
include(CPack)
```

Visual Studio 2019 で使用するため、CMakeLists.txt があるフォルダーから、
以下のコマンドを入力し、slnファイルを作成しました。

```
cmake -G "Visual Studio 16 2019" -A x64 .
```

同一フォルダーにslnファイルが完成しており、無事に Visual Studio 2019 でコンパイル成功しました。

その完成したフォルダー一式を、違うPCにコピーして、再度、Visual Studio 2019 でコンパイルすると、前回の違うPCでのpathが通っており、コンパイルエラーになります。

違うPCでも相対的にコンパイル出来るような方法はあるのでしょうか。

Answer (score 1):

違うPCではcmakeからやり直せば良いだけのことなのでは？

Comment: 違うPCでcmakeからやり直すことで問題ありませんでした。

Answer (score 1):

[Visual Studioはcmake対応](https://docs.microsoft.com/ja-jp/cpp/build/cmake-projects-in-visual-studio?view=msvc-170#ide-integration)しているので、slnファイルは生成せずにそれぞれの環境で「Open a local folder」を実行することをお勧めします。

Comment: 「Open a local folder」から開く方法を試したところ、自動的にcmakeが動いて成功しました。
その後、ビルドを実施すると実行形式exeファイルが生成されていました。

フォルダー一式を違うPCにコピーして、同様に実施すると成功しました。